# Unable to update security group rule across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

**Terraform Version**: v0.11.8

I am trying to update the rule of security group which is in another region (Ireland) after deploying my current security group (Ohio).

Below is my code snippet:

```
variable "aws_account_id" {}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
}

provider "aws" {
  region              = "us-east-2"
  allowed_account_ids = ["${var.aws_account_id}"]
}

provider "aws" {
  alias               = "TestApp"
  region              = "eu-west-1"
}


data "aws_security_group" "test_sg" {
  provider        = "aws.TestApp"
  name = "test-sg"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test1_sg" {
  name        = "Test 1"
  vpc_id      = "VPC ID"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_test1_access_test_sg" {
  provider        = "aws.TestApp"

  type            = "ingress"
  from_port       = "80"
  to_port         = "80"
  protocol        = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "${data.aws_security_group.test_sg.id}"

  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.test1_sg.id}"
}
```

I am getting circular dependency like below.

**Case 1**: Run above code, Getting error that `test1_sg` security group does not exist.

**Case 2**: Run above code without `provider = "aws.TestApp"` in `aws_security_group_rule`, Getting error that test_sg security group does not exist.

**Case 3**: Run above code without `provider = "aws.TestApp"` in `data "aws_security_group" "test_sg"` , Getting error that test_sg security group does not exist.

I am not sure this is 100% issue of inter-region communication but it seems like this is the case.

Note: The above error is coming while running terraform apply. Plan is showing correct change without any error.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so finally i found the answer.

**As per Amazon documentation...**

> You cannot reference the security group of a peer VPC that's in a
>   different region. Instead, use the CIDR block of the peer VPC.

[AWS Doc: Updating Your Security Groups to Reference Peer VPC Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-security-groups.html)

I need to use cidr block instead of the security group while referencing in cross region.

Comment: does aws have any plans of lifting this limitation in the future?

Comment: Not sure, I can't find any open issue related to that. Keep checking documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see with your case 1, your source security group should be "test1_sg". There is no security group with the name "test1_access_test2". Use this.

```
source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.test1_sg.id}"
```

Otherwise, go and check on your console whether that security group exists or not.

Comment: Good catch. I have updated the question. But still the issue is same :)